# Erase various values of a list if it matches to the values of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code and what I want is to erase all the values of the list `hand` that are repeated four times.

```
value=["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
sign=["T", "D", "C", "P"]
hand=["AD", "AC", "2D", "3C", "4C", "AT", "AP", "2C", "2P", "2T"]
counter1=0
counter2=0
while counter2<=12:
    for x in value:
        for y in sign:
            z=x+y
            if z in [value[counter2]+c for c in sign]:
                    counter1+=1
    if counter1==4:
        for x in [value[counter2]+c for c in sign]:
            hand.remove(x)
    counter1=0
    counter2+=1
print(hand)
```

As you can see, I tried the `while` loop but it gives me a `ValueError`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

if you need the value of hand to be

```
hand=["2D", "3C", "4C", "2C", "2P", "2T"]
```

you need to run

```
from collections import Counter

# get the values in hand
values_in_hand = [h[0] for h in hand]

# create a dict with the count of ocurrences in hand 
count = Counter(values_in_hand)

# get only the items where the value is different from 4
clean_hand = [h for h in hand if count[h[0]] != 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a frequency dictionary:

```
value_freq = {v:[h[0] for h in hand].count(v) for v in set([h[0] for h in hand])}
clean_hand = [h for h in hand if value_freq[h[0]]!=4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your algorithm after some fix :

```
value=["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
sign=["T", "D", "C", "P"]
hand=["AD", "AC", "2D", "3C", "4C", "AT", "AP", "2C", "2P", "2T"]
counter1=0
counter2=0
while counter2<=12:
    for x in value:
        for y in sign:
            z=x+y

            if z in hand:

                counter1+=1

        if counter1==4:
            for x in [value[counter2]+c for c in sign]:
                hand.remove(x)
        counter1=0
        counter2+=1
print(hand)
```

output:

```
['3C', '4C']
```

But you can also do this task in steps as :

> first step :

groupby all index[0] same items in hand:

```
compare_list={}

for i in hand:
    data=list(i)
    if data[0] not in compare_list:
        compare_list[data[0]]=[i]
    else:
        compare_list[data[0]].append(i)

print(compare_list)
```

output:

```
{'3': ['3C'], '2': ['2D', '2C', '2P', '2T'], '4': ['4C'], 'A': ['AD', 'AC', 'AT', 'AP']}
```

> step 2:

Now create the combinations from value and sign list:

```
data4=[[i+j for j in sign] for i in value]
print(data4)
```

which will give:

```
[['AT', 'AD', 'AC', 'AP', 'Ao'], ['2T', '2D', '2C', '2P', '2o'], ['3T', '3D', '3C', '3P', '3o'], ['4T', '4D', '4C', '4P', '4o'], ['5T', '5D', '5C', '5P', '5o'], ['6T', '6D', '6C', '6P', '6o'], ['7T', '7D', '7C', '7P', '7o'], ['8T', '8D', '8C', '8P', '8o'], ['9T', '9D', '9C', '9P', '9o'], ['10T', '10D', '10C', '10P', '10o'], ['JT', 'JD', 'JC', 'JP', 'Jo'], ['QT', 'QD', 'QC', 'QP', 'Qo'], ['KT', 'KD', 'KC', 'KP', 'Ko']]
```

> Final_step:

Now just check if compare list have any item which len==4 and all items are also present in any sublist of combinations then just delete the key :

But instead of deleting keys from origional dict create a copy of dict and delete keys from there:

```
final_list=deepcopy(compare_list)

for value_1,hand_1 in compare_list.items():
    if len(hand_1)==4:
        for item in data4:
            if set(hand_1).issubset(item) or set(item).issubset(hand_1):
                del final_list[value_1]
print(final_list.values())
```

outout:

```
dict_values([['3C'], ['4C']])
```